# How to parse the output of one rule and use it as a wildcard in the input of the next rule (Snakemake)?

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

On my Snakemake workflow, I have a rule that generates a table. I would like to parse the table and use the values of one of the columns as wildcard for the next rule. Reading the Snakemake documentation related to wildcards, I was thinking to use a function to define the wildcards for the input and then call it using a lambda function in the input. Something like this:

```
def getNames(table):
  table = pd.read_csv("path/to/file/table.tsv")
  id = table.loc[,["fasta_id"]]
  return id

rule A:
   input: 
       file = "path/to/file/A.txt",
       database = "path/to/file/database.txt"
   output:
       table = "path/to/file/table.tsv"
   shell:
       "somecommand {input.file} {input.database} > {output.table}
  
rule B:
   input: 
     lambda wildcards: expand("path/to/file/{fasta_id}.fasta", getnames, wildcards.fasta_id)
   output:
     "path/to/file/fasta.gsm"
   shell:
     "somecommand {input} {output}"
```

Of course this type of code does not work on my tests but I was wondering if it is feasible to do it. Another option that I was thinking is to define a sub-workflow. Ideas? Any help will be completely appreciated!

Thank you very much for your consideration!